# Make a List with some of the items from Results in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

What I want to do is make a `List` with items from a `Results`. What I have is a UITableView which was populated from `Results`. From this table I want to create a `List` when the user selects rows, but for some reason nothing gets appended to the `List` when I append items from the Results to the List when the rows are selected.

Here is the code I have:

Realm Object:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Fruit:Object{
    dynamic var fruitName:String = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}
```

ViewController:

```
var fruits: Results<Fruit>!
var fruitSelectionList: List<Fruit>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateFruits()

    tableFruits.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    tableFruits.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
}    

func updateFruits(){
    fruits = realm.objects(Fruit.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "fruitName")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let index = fruitSelectionList?.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
        try! realm.write {
            fruitSelectionList?.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {
        try! realm.write {
            // nothing gets appended here, why?
            fruitSelectionList?.append(fruits[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let index = fruitSelectionList?.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
        fruitSelectionList?.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that similar code without using Realm works just fine...

Plain Swift code that works when not using Realm:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    var fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Watermelon", "Peaches"]

    var newFruitList:[String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    @IBAction func makeSelection(_ sender: Any) {
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let item = fruits[indexPath.row]
        if let index = newFruitList.index(of: item) {
            newFruitList.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            newFruitList.append(fruits[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let index = newFruitList.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
            newFruitList.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make a `List` with some items from a `Results`?

FYI - The only reason I need to create the `List` is to be able to add and remove items on a table row selection otherwise I would stick with just  Results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not the same at all when not using `Realm`. The issue has nothing to do with `Realm`, it is about wrongly declaring the `List`s.

You declare them as implicitly unwrapped optionals (which you shouldn't do in the first place), then try to append a `nil` list. You cannot append `nil`, you need an empty `List` in the first place. If you didn't use safe unwrapping of the optionals, you would get a runtime exception instead of a `nil` result.

Declare `fruitSelectionList` as an empty `List` and you won't have this issue.

```
var fruits: Results<Fruit>?
var fruitSelectionList = List<Fruit>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let index = fruitSelectionList?.index(of: fruits[indexPath.row]) {
        fruitSelectionList.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        fruitSelectionList.append(fruits[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Moreover, `fruitSelectionList` is not managed by `Realm`, since only `Results` are automatically updating, so you don't need to put your actions on `fruitSelectionList` inside write transactions. You also don't actually need `fruitSelectionList` to be of type `List`, it could be an `Array` as well.

Just a general piece of advice: if you need your selections to be persisted, I would advise you to update your `Fruit` model class to have a `selected` property of type `Bool` and update that property when a row of the tableView is selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and your good advice, I appreciate it. I love Realm!

Comment: The part about the List not being managed by Realm was critical to an issue that I was having. Trick I'm using to remember is that Results and Realm both start with R.